# How to remove lag when using more than 50,000 options in <select> tag in html??

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I am fetching options for the dropdown menu from database.
I have already used select2.js but it is not working.
Whenever I click on the dropdown menu the page stops responding.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see **[ask]** and **[mcve]**. [edit] question to add code.

Comment: Why would you even consider giving the user 50,000 options in the first place?

Comment: You are having an interface design problem causing a browser problem

Comment: You need to fetch these in a more efficient way. Dropping 50k of them on the page is not going to end well. Seems like you need a lookup which returns relevant results.

Comment: If you require your user to choose from 50.000 different options, a dropdown will never be a rational choice -- and this is not a performance issue, but an UI/UX consideration. My recommendation would be to consider using a search field instead, with dynamic auto-complete that only shows the, say, 20 most relevant suggestions for the user's input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't use that many options. This is not only slow, but also uncomfortable.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: There is only one way to remove lag — don't use 50000 options.